# Does the order always matter in a statement with qualifiers?

Tags: logic

Consider the statement $\forall u \in \mathbb{N}, \exists v \in \mathbb{N} \backslash \{u\} \text{ such that } \frac{v}{n} \in \mathbb{N}$. Negating this statement produces $\exists u \in \mathbb{N} \mid \forall v \in \mathbb{N}, \frac{u}{v} \notin \mathbb{N}$. However, is it equivalent for me to swap these around and say $\exists u \in \mathbb{N} \mid \frac{u}{v} \notin \mathbb{N} \forall v \in \mathbb{N}$? My gut feeling tells me you can't always move things around like that but I can't really see anything wrong with it either.

Comment: Before you quantify $v$, it's a free variable. So $\exists u(\frac uv\notin\Bbb N)\forall v$ is not even a well-formed formula.

Comment: If you want to be purely symbolic, you should really put all your quantifiers at the front and your predicate at the end. If you're not doing that, then you should probably stick to words: for example you might say "there exists $u \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $u/v \not \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $v \in \mathbb{N}$".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the order matters.  Compare these (one in an excerpt from the definition of continuity, the other is a modification with the quantifiers switched around):

1. For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that we have:
   $$
   |f(x) - f( x + h)| < \epsilon \mbox{ for all $h$ with $|h| \delta$}.
   $$
2. There exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have:
   $$
   |f(x) - f( x + h)| < \epsilon \mbox{ for all $h$ with $|h| \delta$}.
   $$

The second condition is much stronger: it holds only for a function that is constant in a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: This is not quite what the question is about.

Comment: The question seems to be about the unfortunate notation of a parenthetical "for all n" at the end of a statement, rather than the swapping of quantifiers at the head of a statement (where they really should be).